# foreach loop not producing variables correctly - listview columns

Tags: c#, foreach, objectlistview

I'm afraid I'm with a basic issue (probably too tired at the time)

I'm generating multiple objects with a foreach loop as it follows:

```
 List<string> columnnames = new List<string> {"column 1", "column 2", "column 3"};
            int i = 0;           
            foreach (string col in columnnames)
            {
                var col1 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn(col, col);
                col1.AspectGetter = x => (x as NodeN).Columns[i];
                this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(col1);
                i++;
            }
```

But the results are incorrect, and only work if I generate every column by itself such as:

```
var col1 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("", "");
            col1.AspectGetter = x => (x as NodeN).Columns[0];
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(col1);

            var col2 = new BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVColumn("", "");
            col2.AspectGetter = x => (x as NodeN).Columns[1];
            this.treeListView1.Columns.Add(col2);
```

I did try setting `col1 = null;` at the end of foreach loop, but this unfortunately is not producing the same results.
I also seem to have an index error unless I set i with maximum value of 2 on the 2nd line of the foreachloop.

Any hint what can be wrong?

Comment: `col1.AspectGetter = x => (x as NodeN).Columns[i];` Whatever this is casting to likely has only 2 "columns" that are applicable to the OVLColumn itself, not the columns of the Excel document etc. you are reading. So your "Foreach" it going through a set of 3 columns to add to your TreeView, but I suspect that above line does not actually do what you expect it to do. For instance as far as I can tell that wouldn't do anything like read a "Column 1" vs "Column 2" etc from a source, it is pointing at "columns" within the OLVColumn object you are creating.

Comment: I think it has to do with the declaration of col1. If you are correct, why would it work outside a foreach loop, but not inside? @StevePy

Comment: Your 2nd example is just using Columns[0] and [1], the foreach is incrementing beyond that.. The question is what the AspectGetter expression and that NodeN.Columns actually refers to.